# What's the meaning of an increased SMD after inverse propensity weight matching?

Tags: propensity-scores, matching, weighted-regression, standardized-mean-difference

I made an inverse propensity weight matching for my research project (two groups, treated and control) and after I observed for some covariates an increased standardized mean difference. What is its meaning?

Comment: It means balance got worse and you should try a different specification to estimate the weights.

Comment: It's so strange because all covariates except one have a SMD decreased with absolute standardized difference < 10%.

Comment: In that case, it means balance on all covariates except that one got better, while balance on that one covariate got worse. You could try a different IPW estimator; you might be interested in doubly-robust weighting. Or you can just replace IPW with a (nonparametric) regression that controls for the confounding variables, which is what I personally would suggest.

Comment: @DaniloFranco that is a very common thing to happen. It even happens in the main vignettes for [`WeightIt`](https://ngreifer.github.io/WeightIt/) and [`twang`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/twang/vignettes/twang.pdf), two of the most common R packages for IPW. This is why it is so critical to assess balance after weighting.

Comment: @ClosedLimelikeCurves those are good approaches, but a weakness they have is that you can't assess how well they are working to remove bias due to the covariates. With IPW it is very clear which features of the covariate distributions are imbalanced. Using regression after IPW for variance reduction is almost always a good idea, though.

Comment: Thank you so much for your contributes. I would like to show that my outcome is different between two groups that undergo two types of treatments. First I made a logistic binary regression (treatment yes/no) with all interested covariates and then used the propensity score to obtain the inverse propensity weight. Then, I stabilized the weight score and calculated the SMD for all covariates. At the end I performed a univariate weight analysis (with my treatment as factor) to check if my outcome is still different between my two groups. How do you suggest me to continue?

Comment: Oh, if you’re estimating IPW with a logistic regression, chances are a nonparametric regression where you control for covariates will have less bias *and* less variance.

Comment: You can use more complicated nonparametric IPW methods to get even less bias than you get from controlling with nonparametric regression, but this can get complicated quickly, and your results are never going to be perfectly unbiased anyways (since you always have *some* unmeasured confounders).

Comment: @Noah it’s 100% correct that IPW methods let you evaluate bias more easily, but I like nonparametric regression better because they’re usually better at minimizing the total error, which I think of as the more important metric. They’re also a lot easier to explain IME.

Comment: That being said, regression after weighting is definitely an improvement, and I can see the appeal of IPW from a frequentist standpoint. I personally tend to be a lot less interested in exactly unbiased estimation, since I come from a Bayesian background.